# Set maximum limit of products purchased from a store for a day (not per customer or cart)

Tags: product, configurable-product, orders

We are using Magento for a bakery website. There is a limit in the number of products that can be served per day (not for a single customer or cart, but for the whole store)...

1. The number of chicken bread rolls shown in the website is 100
   (inventory..>Qty..>100)
2. On 30/Sept/2016, the maximum order can be placed (by total number of customers) is 20 (suppose we have the ability to make 20 chicken bread rolls only on a day - this 20 can be ordered by a single customer or by many customers). Oct 1st,2nd etc -Daily - this can be the case.

Comment: What about updating the stock qty each day, based on the number of products you have made for that day?

Comment: Other than editing daily, is there any built in solution?

Comment: No, there is no built-in substitution for this